# Visiting Neuschwanstein on December 31

Tags: germany, landmarks

The website states that the Neuschwanstein Castle is closed on December 31st. Will the view points be closed as well? I do not wish to have a guided tour of the inside part of the castle. I would only like to view the castle from certain view points, eg. Marienbrücke.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From previous visits: the parking lots will also be closed, as will be the restaurants and any horse-carts or stuff that taxis you uphill. The Marienbrücke is in publicly accessible forest, as is the exterior of the castle, so if you are willing to park on the side of the road, and *walk* up the hill (about a mile, but steep uphill, potentially in snow and ice), you will be able to access those locations.
There are alternative hikes to the paved road too, through the forest.

Note that the Marienbrücke is often closed in Winter for safety reasons (snow and ice), which might result in you not being able to go onto it.